# Create lines in the Axapta journal

Tags: c#, wcf, axapta

I do WCF-srvice on C# which must get data from Axapta's tables. I can create new `AxaptaRecord`, and create new record in table.

```
using (axRecord = axapta.CreateAxaptaRecord(tableName)) //this create new record
{
    axRecord.set_Field("name", "firstname");
    -//-
    axRecord.Insert();
}
```

This code show, how I get data from this tables.

```
using (axRecord = axapta.CreateAxaptaRecord(tableName))
{
    axRecord.ExecuteStmt("select * from %1");
    while (axRecord.Found)
    {
        ToroEquipment temp=new ToroEquipment();
        temp.num_journal=axRecord.get_Field("text").ToString();
        lToroEq.Add(temp);
        axRecord.Next();
    }
}
```

Also, all tables can have linked table, which contain lines with other data. 
[image: I try to show it on picture]

I can read data from this lines. I use the above code with the modified query (I add condition with "where").

So, how can I insert data from this lines in C#?
Can you give me some examples of code for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the .NET Business Connector, not AIF.
So you can find an example to insert data using the .NET BC here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa868997.aspx

If you want to use WCF, you can activate the LedgerServices service group and add the LedgerGeneralJournalService document datasource and use it directly as WCF service.